# How to detect click on an object in OpenGL ES in Android application?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my Android application, I have a bunch of meshes in a collection that are moving around in 3D space. I want something to happen to the mesh when any one of the moving mesh (objects) are touched. How can I detect which object has been tapped / clicked?

Answer (score 5):

In your View, you will need to override [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)() and determine if the touch event occurred on one of your objects. The [Android Dev Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html) has some examples on handling touch events.

Comment: I know about onTtouchEvent. It only gives me x,y location where the touch was done. The question is how can I determine which of the moving mesh (if any) in 3d space was touched on?

Comment: You will need to manually figure out if the x,y is within the mesh.

Comment: have you got any solutions @ace

Answer (score 3):

[Ray picking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093096/implementing-ray-picking).