# convert window coordinates to 3D world coordinates with glut function glutMouseFunc()

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, mouse, glut

I am trying to get the 3D coordinates of a mouse click C++/OpengGL with the glut function glutMouseFunc(). So I created a function like this:

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
{
    mouse_x=x;
    mouse_y=y;
    }
}
```

The function gets the window coordinates of the click of the mouse and i use it with the glut function glutMouseFunc() like this:

```
  glutMouseFunc(mouse);
```

My question is how would I modify the coordinates given by the mouse function so I could use them in a 3D world. My exact purpose would be the following: to be able to see if I have clicked on a 3D shape drawn in the world.

[EDIT] Would it be easier to transform the coordinates of the 3D object to 2D window coordinates and then compare it to the coordinates of the mouse click?

Comment: Same question (in principle) as http://stackoverflow.com/q/2093096/524368

Answer (score 0):

Mouse click does not correspond to a point in 3d space, but to a ray.

In any case, you use [gluUnProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml).

If you know scene "depth" under cursor, then you can get 3d position of a click - by passing depth via `winZ` parameter.

If you don't know depth, pass 0.0 in `winZ` parameter, to get start of the ray, and 1.0 to get the "end". You'll have to calculate yourself if this ray hits anything.