# In Android, OpenGL, I want to draw a circle dynamically using motion event with centre as midpoint of device screen, but not getting desired output

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

The following is the code that I used to draw a circle by getting the touch position from the screen and calculating the radius from the origin to the touch point and passing to the renderer to draw the circle.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float ex=0, ey=0;
    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ex = (e.getX()/(getWidth()/2))-1;
            ey = 1-(e.getY()/(getHeight()/2));
             dist = (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ex, 2)+Math.pow(ey, 2)));
    }
   mRenderer.radius = dist;
    requestRender();
    return true;
}
```

But I am getting the circle drawn at a radius lesser compared to the touch point I give for radius. i.e. the output doesn't coincide with the touch event.  I want to know is there any Touch Scale Factor for arriving the touch posistion and how to employ it in the code ?

Comment: The problem is not only to convert the screen coordinates to the OpenGL ES coordinate system, but also to integrate this conversion into the projection and camera views. I'm looking forward for an answer for this annoying problem too.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to consider the projection and view matrices,as 5agado pointed out.

You can use Ray Picking for that: it basically consists in tracing a Ray from the touched point in the screen to your scene. In your case, you need to compute the intersection point of this Ray with your drawing surface.

You can take a look at [this](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093096/implementing-ray-picking)