# Manual mouse ray picking ray calculation in java rotation problem

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, ray, picking

I am having trouble finishing my mouse ray picking algorithm for a game I am creating using java (and opengl/lwjgl). I implemented ray tracing using inspiration from [here](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093096/implementing-ray-picking). I followed [a lwjgl book](https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/) for the implementation of the game. The following code is the mouse ray picking algorithm:

```java
// Calculate the normalized device coordinates
Vector2d mouseCoords = mouseInput.getPositionVector();
mouseCoords.mul((float)2 / window.width(), (float)2 / window.height());           
Vector4f mouseNDS = new Vector4f((float)mouseCoords.x, (float)mouseCoords.y, -1f, 1f);     

// Calculate the ray in cam space 
Vector4f eyeRay = mouseNDS.mul(renderer.getTransformations().getProjectionMatrix().invert());
eyeRay = new Vector4f(eyeRay.x, eyeRay.y, eyeRay.z, 0f);

// Calculate the ray in world space
Vector4f worldRay4f = eyeRay.mul(renderer.getTransformations().getViewMatrix(camera).invert());
Vector3f worldRay = new Vector3f(worldRay4f.x, worldRay4f.y, -worldRay4f.z).normalize();
```

Eventually, I want to intersect it with the ground plane (y = 0). This is my code for this:

```java
float lambda = camera.getPos().dot(new Vector3f(0, 1f , 0)) / worldRay.dot(new Vector3f(0, 1f, 0));      

Vector3f ray_scaled = worldRay.mul(lambda);
Vector3f ground_vec = new Vector3f();
camera.getPos().sub(ray_scaled, ground_vec);
```

This code works only if the camera is pointing in the negative y direction (i.e. directly down), and keeps working when I apply a position change. However, if I rotate the camera, the code breaks, i.e. the ground vector does not end under the mouse position anymore.

I suspect something is wrong with the inversion of the viewMatrix of the camera. The viewMatrix is calculated by this code:

```java
public Matrix4f getViewMatrix(Camera camera) {
        Vector3f cameraPos = camera.getPos();
        Vector3f rotation = camera.getRot();

        viewMatrix.identity();
        viewMatrix.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(rotation.x), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0))
                  .rotate((float)Math.toRadians(rotation.y), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0))
                  .rotate((float)Math.toRadians(rotation.z), new Vector3f(0, 0, 1));
        viewMatrix.translate(-cameraPos.x, -cameraPos.y, -cameraPos.z);
        return viewMatrix;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue when you set the world ray (`worldRay`). The `z` component has not to be inverted:

<s>`Vector3f worldRay = new Vector3f(worldRay4f.x, worldRay4f.y, -worldRay4f.z).normalize();`</s>

```java
Vector3f worldRay = new Vector3f(worldRay4f.x, worldRay4f.y, worldRay4f.z).normalize();
```

If the camera points in the negative y direction, then the `x` and `z` component of `worldRay4f` is 0.0 and the error is not noticeable.

---

The origin of the window coordinates is at the top left. In normalized device space the top left is (-1, 1) and the bottom left is (-1, -1). So the y coordinate has to be flipped when transforming the mouse coordinate to normalized device space:

```java
Vector2d mouseCoords = mouseInput.getPositionVector();
Vector4f mouseNDS = new Vector4f(
    (float)mouseCoords.x * 2f / window.width() - 1f,
    1f - (float)mouseCoords.y * 2f / window.height(),
    -1f, 1f);
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually sounds very logical. When I remove this negation, the vector is flipped on the z-axis, however, I looked further and found that I need to negate the y coordinate of the normalized device coordinates as follows:
```
Vector4f mouseNDS = new Vector4f((float)mouseCoords.x, - (float)mouseCoords.y, -1f, 1f);
```
It now works for all transformations of the camera!

Comment: @Joris The origin of the window coordinates is at the top left. The minimum of the NDC is at the bottom left. So the y coordinate has to be flipped.